# Replacing arrows by figures

Tags: plotting

with the help of the **Custom arrow shaft** question I have been able to obtain the following little fish.[image]

Now I wonder  how could I use it in substitution for the arrows in any plot like fields, streamplots or whatever ?

A second question is the following : could the Strokarea function be used to clip an image ?

Comment: `ArrowHeads` is a graphics directive, so I don't think you can use it outside of that context.

Comment: @Feyre I suppose you can use `Inset` to make a image into a Graphics directive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will use a left to right fish (for direction purpose).

```
fish = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxg8m.png"];
fish = ImageReflect[fish, Left -> Right]
```

[image]

Let say this is the vector field where you want to replace the fish. With standard convention the list contains {`Origin`,`Endpoint with respect to origin`}.

```
data = Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, {y, -x}}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], 1];
ListVectorPlot[data]
```

[image]

So I define the `fishy arrow`

```
scale = 0.1;
fishead[{{x_, y_}, {a_, b_}}] := Inset[fish, {x, y}, Automatic, scale Norm[{a, b}], {a, b}]
```

`scale` is to control the relative size (like `Arrowheads`). And finally plot with `Graphics`.

```
Graphics[fishead[#] & /@ data, Frame->True]
```

[image]

---

For swarming Dory:

```
fish = Import["http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-hing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=\105354545"];
fish = ColorReplace[ImageCrop[fish], White]
scale = 0.15;
fishead[{{x_, y_}, {a_, b_}}] := Inset[fish, {x, y}, Automatic, scale Norm[{a, b}], {a, b}]
Graphics[fishead[#] & /@ data, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}]
```

[image]

This will work for any image with a unicolour background. Just change the `ColorReplace` argument if it is not white.

Comment: We want Nemo... or Dory.

Comment: @YvesKlett, I would prefer Bruce for an arrow. Anyway, beware of copyright. You don't want to write a paper with a Dory-graph and then suddenly find Pixar to be the first author ;-)

Comment: ... Ichthylicious!

Comment: Neither my fish nor Dory are fine for this job but i think to use perhaps an elongated water drop.